# Androidviewclient features

Tags: androidviewclient

I am still using AndroidViewClient version 10.5. Does the new version 10.7 implement new features as a monkey replacement and support unicodes raised on this post [AndroidViewClient's device.touch() is much slower than MonkeyRunner's. Can it be fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491862/androidviewclients-device-touch-is-much-slower-than-monkeyrunners-can-it-be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the log containing the description of the changes at https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/commits/master.

The solutions for both problems you mentioned are in progress and the needed support is part of the changes in latest version (check for UiAutomatorHelper). Basically, UiAutomatorHelper will run as a REST server on the device and the interaction would take place through it.

Comment: oh that is really great, I will look closely to the codes. Basically how do you start the REST server on the device, for example via adb with a dedicated port and then use port redirection and http requests to send commands to the server ?

Comment: Everything will be automatic and transparent, no manual steps involved.

Comment: fantastic, I am really looking forward for the uiautomator to work...for the moment I must use 2 mobile devices to reach my target, I am quite sure with the uiautomator I will need only 1 mobile device to reach the same target, in the long it will spare money, so you can imagine the importance of the speed for such cases :)